# High performance/High volume table/index

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database, database-performance

We have a table (Azure SQL) that is indexed only by a GUID, similar to:

```
    CREATE TABLE Instances
        (orgId int not null,
        guid varchar(64) not null,  <-- non unique, can repeat up to 1,000 times
        column3 varchar(64) not null,
        column4 varchar(64) not null,
        column5 int not null,
        column6 datetime)

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX index1 ON Instances (guid);
```

The table has about 5 million inserts in a timeframe of 8 hours (critical process).

Then (after), we process and remove the previous day's records (not so critical).

The process is repeated every day.

Sometimes, we can see how the insertion performance downgrades after several hours, up to 10X.

The question is: Is there a way to maintain or increase the insertion performance? Do we need something different in the table or index design?

Comment: To clarify, we don't perform any kind of bulk insert. Rows are added individually.

Comment: Are you using Standard, Premium, vCore? On what tier is your database?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani it is vCore-based

Comment: what tier of vCore?

Answer (score 1):

5 millions insert in 8 hours =

- 10,000 insert per minute
- 180 insert per second

This means that your database is constantly under pressure.

Solutions:

1. **Try cache the insert at application level:** stop inserting every second, cache the insert at application level and run a routine every minutes that insert in bulk. (just test, it might work, it might not work).
2. **Try Azure SQL Edge:** [Azure SQL Edge](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/azure-sql/edge/) it's optimized for IoT and data streaming.
3. **Try Azure SQL Database Hyperscale:** [Azure SQL Database Hyperscale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tier-hyperscale?view=azuresql) is more scalable